# Substitution lemma for many-sorted logic interpretation in a topos

Tags: logic, category-theory, topos-theory

Goldblatt's "Topoi" suggests the following exercise (16.3.2). Let $\varphi$ be some formula of some many-sorted language, and let $u$ be some term of the same sort as some free variable $v_i$ in $\varphi$. Show that the following is a pullback:

[image]

assuming all the usual things about variable capture/freeness, and where $\varphi(v_i/u)$ is the original formula with the $v_i$ variable substituted by the term $u$, $\mathbf{v} = (v_1 : a_1, ..., v_n : a_n)$ is a list of variables appropriate to the formula $\varphi$, $\mathbf{u}$ is one for $\varphi(v_i/u)$, $\mathcal{M}(\mathbf{v}) = \mathcal{M}(a_1) \times \dots \times \mathcal{M}(a_n)$, and $\mathcal{M}|v_i/u| : \mathcal{M}(\mathbf{v}) \rightarrow \mathcal{M}(\mathbf{u})$ projects $v_j$s out of $\mathbf{u}$ except for $v_i$, the latter being replaced by $\mathcal{M}^\mathbf{u}(u)$.

I've managed to do almost all of the cases for the structural induction on $\varphi$ except when it's quantified. So let's try show this for $(\forall w. \varphi)$. Here's the diagram I've been considering (where I denote $\varphi(v_i/u)$ as $\hat\varphi$):

[image]

The left face of this half-cube is our induction hypothesis, and I can see why the bottom one commutes. The orange dotted arrow on the right is what needs to be proven to:

1. exist, and
2. make it a pullback,

and I'm failing to see even just the existence. How do I construct this arrow, let alone prove it's the pullback we need?

Comment: If you have a corresponding result for single-sorted languages, maybe you could just translate the many-sorted language into an equivalent single-sorted language?  The idea would be to add unary predicates $t_i$ for each sort, and replace e.g. $(\forall x^i)\varphi$ with $(\forall x)(t_i(x) \rightarrow \varphi)$ and $(\exists x^i)\varphi$ with $(\exists x)(t_i(x) \land \varphi)$.

Comment: Goldblatt defines interpretations for single-sorted languages somewhat differently, especially in the quantifiers part (and he defines $\forall$ and $\exists$ somewhat differently for those), so the mapping'd be hard. And, TBH, I was curious if the statement can be proven from functorial/adjointness considerations, being an insightful rather than technical exercise — $\forall_{\pi^\mathbf{v}_w}$ is adjoint to the pullback functor induced by $\pi^\mathbf{v}_w$ and so is $\exists_{\pi^\mathbf{v}_w}$, and the second diagram hints very strongly this might be used, but I just can't take that hint!